# How to implement a server on Android during play

Tags: android, godot, mobile

I'm developing a chess game for mobile. In Godot, you can set up a UDP connection with PacketPeerUdp. My problem is establishing a process that acts as a server and runs the already compiled (armv8) chess engine file. Unlike on PC, where I can write code in C++, compile it, and run it as a separate process, on mobile that won't work. Do I need to create an executable file through Android Studio or is there a simpler way to solve this?